# web forms, decompile dll, how to get layout files?

Tags: layout, webforms

I have web form dll (.net) and I successfully decompile it by dotPeek. And also exported it to solution.
BUT, I get only *.aspx.cs files and no *.aspx with layout.

It`s possible? How?
Thanks.

Comment: aspx and ascx file are not in DLL. There should be there where the DLL was probably in some other folder.

Comment: Doh! :-) Thank You for answer.